# How do how you set security rules in Cloud Firestore so that a logged in user may only read documents that THEY posted

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have tried the same things that the docs and other sources say to do. For some reason it is not working. All I need to do is set it up so that a logged in user can only read their own todos and expenses. As of now I can only get it to render ALL of the documents (regardless of uid) from the collections, or none. Below are the security rules I currently have. It will get and render all of the documents in the todos collection, but none from the expenses collection. I am very confused.

```
service cloud.firestore {
match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /todos/{todo} {
    allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null
  }
  match /users/{userId} {
    allow create
    allow read: if request.auth.uid == userId
    allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId

    match /expenses/{expense} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null
      allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId
      }
    }
  }
```

}

the component is set up like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import TodoSummary from './TodoSummary'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const TodosList = ({ todos }) => {
  return (
    <div className="section">
      {todos && todos.map(todo => {
        return (
          <Link to={'/todo/' + todo.id} key={todo.id}>
            <TodoSummary todo={todo} id={todo.id} />
          </Link>
        )
      })}

    </div>
  )
}

export default TodosList
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the query that's not returning the results the way you expect.  Also, I'm confused by your statement that "*all of the examples online of setting security rules are with what appears to be the way firebase USED to format them*".  The Firestore examples in the documentation all look OK to me.

Comment: the format in most of the sources I've found is like this

`{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}`

I'm not sure if I'm formatting it incorrectly or if there are other ways accepted for structuring it, but when I mimic code from the current docs, it doesn't solve the problem. For example in this link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions

Comment: That format for rules is for Realtime Database, not Firestore.  They are different products, and don't affect each other at all.  They have different sets of documentation to suit the different formats.

Comment: I see, well that clears that up. I wish the docs went a little more in-depth, as their explanation on how to accomplish what I'm trying to isn't working.

Comment: Security rules are **very** flexible, and it's not possible to document all the different recipes that could apply to every given app.  But better documentation is being worked on.  In any event, like writing code, it can take some creativity to put together the pieces to do what you want.

Comment: BTW you haven't yet done what I've asked in the first comment: "Please edit the question to show the query that's not returning the results the way you expect."

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you mean by that. You want me to put the query in the question itself, or reword the question?

Comment: Yes, put the query in the question.  We need to be able to see what's not working the way you expect.  Your query may not match what your rules are actually doing.  Your query may also be making expectations of your rules that are not what the rules actually do.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to figure out is whether or not I need to write my actual javascript to filter out the documents that belong to another user, or if there is a way to set the security rules so that they make it so that the only ones that are read when that collection is rendered are the ones belonging to the logged in user. It seems logical that you could just do that from manipulating the userId in the security rules in Cloud Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I was insisting that you show your code is because I suspect that you are expecting your security rules to filter out documents from the query.  They will not do that.  Security rules do not act as filters.  From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query):

> When writing queries to retrieve documents, keep in mind that security
>   rules are not filters—queries are all or nothing. To save you time and
>   resources, Cloud Firestore evaluates a query against its potential
>   result set instead of the actual field values for all of your
>   documents. If a query could potentially return documents that the
>   client does not have permission to read, the entire request fails.

Comment: This is how the list component that renders the todos or expenses are mapped over.  As of now it's checking to see that they're there (passed in as props from parent component) and if so, rendering the collection. So I'm getting the idea that I need to modify the logic so that it checks that the associated userId for each document needs to match the ID of the user logged in and only render those ones?

Comment: Bottom line is that any given query should only request documents that the user actually has permission to read.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I was so thrown off by Firebase's docs showing examples of code that express that there ARE ways to set it so that you can read and write only your own data, but there is more depth than that, as Doug mentioned, you need to specify in the query. I used a simple if else statement to check that the auth.uid matches the doc.userId and it filtered the results for just that user for me. Thank you Doug, for setting me on the right path!